# Find n smallest values from data?

Tags: r

How to get 3 minimum value on the data automatically?

Data:

```
data <- c(4,3,5,2,2,1,1,5,6,7,8,9)
[1] 4 3 5 2 2 1 1 5 6 7 8 9
```

With `min()` function just return 1 value and I want to get 3 minimum value from data.

```
min(data)
[1] 1
```

Can I have this from a data?

```
[1] 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 11):

Simply take the first three values of a sorted vector

```
> sort(data)[1:3]
[1] 1 1 2
```

Another alternative is `head` function that shows you the first `n` values of R object, so for three highest numbers you need `head` of a sorted vector

```
> head(sort(data), 3)
[1] 1 1 2
```

...but you could take `head` of possibly any other R object.

If you were interested in value that marks the upper boundry of `k` percent lowest values, use `quantile` function

```
> quantile(data, 0.1)
10% 
1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data <- c(4,3,5,2,2,1,1,5,6,7,8,9)
sort(data,decreasing=F)[1:3]
```